# Passing More Arguments to a Callback Function

Tags: javascript, express

Suppose I have a method that issues a `POST` and then calls an appropriate callback function in order to handle the response:

```
myService.verify(id, verificationCallback);

function verificationCallback(err, response) { ... }
```

Maybe this question is two-fold. There seems to be 2 implicit arguments being passed to `verificationCallback` (is this the case? how does this work?)

How would I then be able to pass in a third argument to that callback? Would I do something like:

```
myService.verify(id, verificationCallback(err, response, someOtherArgument));
```

Would this break because there are no `err` and `response` variables in the current context? Would I access these variables using the `arguments` object?

**Possible Solution (?)**

```
Using an anonymous function:

myService.verify(id, function(err, response) {
    // Access my other variable here
    someOtherArgument === ...
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
myService.verify(id, verificationCallback(err, response, someOtherArgument));
```

This would not work. It would call the function with (most likely) undefined variables immediately.

The arguments are not passed implicitly, but explicitly when the function is invocated inside the verify function. See JonasW's anwer.

Here is a possible solution:

```
function callback(yourThirdArgument) {
    return function(err, response) {
       ...
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
myService.verify(id, callback(someOtherArgument));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `.bind()`. Attach null to the `this` value and `someOtherArgument` will be passed as the first argument to your callback. Here's an [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) link for more info.

```
const someOtherArgument = "";

// Use .bind() to attach an argument to your callback.
myService.verify(id, verificationCallback.bind(null, someOtherArgument));

function verificationCallback(someOtherArgument, err, response) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldnt call that *implicit*:

```
  const myService = {
   verify(id, cb){
    //...
    cb(null, "data"); // <----
   }
 };
```